# 2 sets of next/prev buttons jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

How do I have two set of the next/ prev on a jquery cycle I currently have one set 
here

```
$('#s10').cycle({
    fx:    'fade',
    delay: -1000,
    next:   '#nexttop', 
    prev:   '#prevtop'
});
```

But can't seem to figure out how to add a second set to the next: and prev: lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using IDs like `#nexttop` and `#prevtop`, use a class shared by two distinct elements:

```
$('#s10').cycle({
    fx:    'fade',
    delay: -1000,
    next:   '.next', 
    prev:   '.prev'
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yThgx/

Comment: I actually had this but forget to change it to . instead of a # thank you very much.